# Make Universal (iPhone+iPad) app run on iPhone storyboard on iPad (simulated size)

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, ios-universal-app

I have a universal app that I've previously designed for both iPhone and iPad, now I don't want to work with the iPad storyboard. I know that I can't withdraw iPad support as I've previously published the app as universal. I need to keep my app "Universal" (so that I can update my app without failing verification), but make iPad use the iPhone storyboard in simulation mode. How can I use my iPhone storyboard with iPad in simulation mode? I've deleted the iPad storyboard, and changed the main interface of iPad also to the iPhone storyboard, but now iPad stretches all the view constraints to 768x1024 to fill the screen, giving it an ugly look. I just want to simulate the "iPhone app" (with the 2x button at the corner) but for obvious reasons, I need to keep device mode in "Universal" in project settings. If it's not possible, what is the best practice to programatically limit the whole storyboard to some limited size on the screen to manually make my app run at the same size (or double) of iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you are asking. Once an app is universal it stays universal. You can't suddenly make the app appear to be iPhone-sized on the iPad. The universal app on the iPad will always be full screen. You need to continue properly supported the iPad screen size.

Your only other solution is to create a new iPhone-only app with a new bundle id. Of course this is bad for your existing users.

Comment: would my app get rejected if I programatically run my views at iphone size, but fitting the screen? (just to avoid creating a new storyboard for iPad)

Comment: How can your views be iPhone size but fit the iPad screen? If the iPad version of your universal app doesn't properly make full use of the larger iPad screen, I doubt Apple would approve it.

Comment: by just filling the screen (like the 2x button, but a bit more to fit the whole real estate), but I also doubt the same, I think I'll have to create an iPad storyboard

Answer (score 1):

When you make your app only for iPhone and run it on iPad, there will be 2x scaling button. If you make your app universal, then your view will be stretched on iPad unless you use constraints, or create your screens programmatically regarding iPad and iPhone UI element sizes.